# Sampling from truncated distribution

Tags: self-study, simulation, gibbs

I want to sample from a truncated distribution that appears in a Gibbs sampling scheme.
The full conditional of the distribution is given by

$p(X = k | \ldots) \propto (1 - p)^{k - 1} \mathbb{1} ( s \leq k)$, where $s$ is a positive integer.

This is a truncated geometric distribution. The tehcnique i am following to simulate from this is first to sample a random number from a geometric distribution and then add to this the number $s$.

First off all i want to ask if this that i am doing is right. And after, is there any obsious reason for this simulation to be slow? Or is it slow because i am doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not certain, but I think you should truncate the distribution. That is, simulate the distribution and then remove any values that are below k and then sample from that

Comment: The left truncated geometric distribution is indeed a shifted geometrical, so it seems correct. It shouldn't take long to simulate it though.

Comment: That simulation shouldn't be slow unless either your initial generation of the geometric is unusually slow, or your adding of $s$ is unusually slow. Which is slow, ... and if possible, *why* is it slow? How is the matlab function generating your geometric variable? Are there other steps in your simulation that might be the bottleneck? Have you done timings?

Comment: @Glen_b you were right. In another step the variable s is stochastic. Because of a bad initialization it couldnt find stationary distribution so the number added was extremely big.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the geometric distribution this will work since it (and the exponential for continuous variables) are memoryless meaning that the probability that x = k + s given that x>=k is just the probability that x = k.  This will not however work for any other distributions.

How are you generating the geometric to begin with? that may be what is slowing you down.

Comment: I use the matlab geornd function. so what i am doing is X=geornd(p) + s